# Message not receiving automatically for Telegram CHATBOT funciton using PHP

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

In order to integrate Telegram Chatbot using PHP, I have already followed below steps.

- Server with SSL certificate
- Webhook with working condition
  URL : https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook?url=https://mywebsite.com/path/to/filename.php
- Created ChatBot and have a valid Token

After that, I have made simple PHP file using following line of code.

```
<?php 
define('BOT_TOKEN', 'CHANGE-ME');
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/');


// This is to read incoming message and fetch chatid
$content    = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update     = json_decode($content, true);
$chatID     = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$message    = $update["message"]["text"];

// compose reply
$reply ="";
switch ($message) {
    case "/start":
        $reply =  "Welcome to chatbot world. Type /help to see commands";
        break;
    case "/test":
        $reply =  "test message";
        break;
    case "/hi":
        $reply =  "Hello from ChatBot";
        break;
    case "/help":
        $reply =  "commands: /start , /test , /hi , /help "; 
        break;
    default:
        $reply =  "Something wrong";
}

// send reply
$sendto =API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$reply;
file_get_contents($sendto);

// Create a debug log.txt to check the response/reply from Telegram in JSON format.
// You can disable it by commenting checkJSON.
checkJSON($chatID,$update);
function checkJSON($chatID,$update){

    $myFile = "log.txt";
    $updateArray = print_r($update,TRUE);
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $chatID ."nn");
    fwrite($fh, $updateArray."nn");
    fclose($fh);
}
```

**Although, I am not receiving message properly.**

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure but this might be the case for you.

You just need to make sure that you have successfully **run webhook URL** that start listening your request before messaging in Telegram ChatBot.

**URL** : https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook?url=https://mywebsite.com/path/to/filename.php

As of now, finally, I have successfully created demo of Telegram Chatbot using PHP.

Comment: what is your point? your answer alone make no sense